# Deutsches Wort für “adjacent possible”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich habe ein englisches Buch gelesen (Cal Newport, *So good they can’t ignore you*), in dem mehrfach der Begriff *adjacent possible* auftaucht.

Soweit ich verstanden habe ist es der nächste Schritt nach *cutting edge*, d. h. das Überschreiten einer Spitzenposition, das eine (technische) Neuerung einleitet.

Sätze im Kontext:

> The next big ideas in any field are found right beyond the current cutting edge, in the **adjacent space** that contains the possible new combinations of existing ideas.
>
> A good career mission is similar to a scientific breakthrough — it’s an innovation waiting to be discovered in the **adjacent possible** of your field.
>
> […] she was much too far from the cutting edge to have any hope of surveying the **adjacent possible**, and if she can’t see the **adjacent possible**, she’s not likely to identify a compelling new direction for her work
>
> Once you get to the cutting edge, however, and discover a mission in the **adjacent possible**, you must go after it with zeal: a “big” action.

Ich suche für *adjacent possible* ein passendes, möglichst einzelnes deutsches Wort.

Meine Suche bei [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=adjacent%20possible&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) war nicht erfolgreich.

Comment: Da kann man sich auch die Frage stellen, ob dieser Begriff aus Sicht der englischen Sprache gut gewählt ist. Ich vermute, daß viele ihn in die Kategorie "bullshit" einsortieren werden.

Comment: @MartinPeters warum? Er ist mir in ähnlichen Zusammenhängen öfter begegnet. Ich finde, er sagt ziemlich klar, was der Verfasser sagen möchte.

Comment: @Burki Klar, es ist dieser Management jargon, und es ist natürlich subjektiv wie man das sieht. Es gibt ganze Bücher, wo diese Art Ausdrücke durch den Kakao gezogen werden. Zum generellen Hintergrund kann ich das Buch von Harry G Frankfurt: On Bullshit empfehlen.

Comment: @MartinPeters ich würde zustimmen, daß es ein Fall fürs bullshit Bingo ist, wenn das jemand in einem deutschen Text verwendet. Aber im Englischen scheint es mir eine vernünftige Wortwahl. Aber vielleicht ist das Geschmackssache, oder liegt daran, daß Englisch eben nicht meine Muttersprache ist.

Comment: @Burki Wie gesagt, es ist subjektiv. Hier noch ein Buchtip: http://www.amazon.ca/Your-Call-Is-Important-To/dp/077107042X .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Das Nächstmögliche** taucht hier und da schon als Übersetzung auf.

Answer (score 3):

Die direkte Übersetzung ist das „angrenzende Mögliche“, und ich habe dafür auch eine ganze Fundstelle gehabt (und dann den Tab geschlossen). Viel besser wird es meiner Meinung nach auch nicht werden, der englische Begriff ist ja auch etwas sperrig.

Comment: Vielleicht klingt "angrenzende Möglichkeit" besser, auch wenn es nicht wörtlich übersetzt ist.

Comment: @Robert, ja, das hat auch jemand in der Wikipedia benutzt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde es mit "über den Horizont hinausschauen" übersetzen, also von "Möglichkeiten jenseits unseres aktuellen Horizonts" sprechen.

Answer (score 2):

In den Beispielen ist "adjecent possible" mehrheitlich ein Ort mit Ausdehnung - nicht die darin enthaltenen Möglichkeiten. Das deckt sich auch mit anderen Verwendungen des Wortes, die man online finden kann.
Von daher denke ich, eine semantisch sehr nahe Übersetzung wäre

> Umgebung der Box

oder Variationen davon (ausserhalb der Box, vor der Box, direkt neben der Box).
Nachteile dieser Übersetzung:

- sie hat nicht annähernd den wissenschaftlichen Klang, ist daher in echt wissenschaftlichem Kontext (wo "adjecent possible" ja herkommt) nicht zu gebrauchen
- die Box-Metapher ist hinlänglich bekannt, ebenso die Idee von "outside the box". "Adjacent possible" klingt, als wäre es neu und super innovativ (was es in den Beispielen der Frage meiner Meinung nach nicht wirklich ist)

Answer (score 1):

Perspektive.

Der Text muss mindestens 30 Zeichen lang sein - deswegen müssen Sie hier noch einen Satz Füllstoff lesen.

Comment: "Mein Vorschlag wäre *Perspektive*." würde 30 Zeichen auch füllen.

Comment: Ich möchte -1 geben für den Füllstoffsatz, lasse es aber bleiben, weil Baum.

Comment: @Em1: Dein Vorschlag wäre Perspektive, wenn was? Wenn Du die Idee gehabt hättest? Mein Vorschlag ist aber Perspektive, ganz unbedingt.

Comment: Dann ersetze "wäre" durch "ist", und 30 Zeichen sind immer noch erfüllt.

Comment: Ich denk gar nicht dran. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mein Vorschlag ist:

> Machbarkeitsgrenze

Es unterscheidet sich etwas, weil *adjacent possible* wohl eher das Feld direkt **neben** der Machbarkeitsgrenze bezeichnet (ich bin mir anhand der Beispiele nicht sicher, ob dieseits oder jenseits), ist dafür aber ein etabliertes Wort, das man nicht extra erklären muss.

Comment: Es bezeichnet m.W. üblicherweise die Möglichkeiten (knapp) außerhalb des Machbaren. Beispiel: Die Eisenbahn wird zu so einem "adjacent possible", sobald jemand eine Dampfmaschine erfunden hat.

Answer (score 0):

> new combinations of existing ideas.

Bestehende Ideen und deren Potential zu erkennen könnte auch durch das Sprichwort "über den Tellerrand schauen" ausgedrückt werden. Dabei werden zumeist Dinge gemeint die außerhalb des betrachteten Fachgebietes liegen.
In dieser Bedeutung ist es keine genaue Übersetzung, da das Buch explizit innerhalb des Gebietes argumentiert. Allerdings gibt es natürlich auch den persönlichen Tellerrand, der unter Umständen einen kleineren Radius hat, als das Fachgebiet. Dadurch entsteht ein ähnliche Bedeutung wie Horizont.

Answer (score 0):

Sinngemäß übersetzen könnte man mit **das resultierend mögliche**, da der Begriff m.W. in Situationen gebraucht wird, in welchen beschrieben wird, daß eine Möglichkeit auf vorher erreichten Errungenschaften beruht (also erst aufgrund dieser Errungenschaft zur Möglichkeit wird).